# Como converter uma String desse tipo para um Objeto Date

Tags: java, data, conversão-de-tipo, owl

Estou trabalhando com uma Ontologia no Protegé 4.1 e tenho um DataProperty que é um DateTime.

Estou pegando esse DateTime dessa forma:

```
["2015-06-30T16:38:53"^^xsd:dateTime]
```

Como colocar a data desta forma em um objeto Date do Java? (estou utilizando Java 7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se a *string* está mesmo na forma que apresentou, contendo também o tipo de dados do XML, ou seja, `["2015-06-30T16:38:53"^^xsd:dateTime]`, uma forma de fazer seria antes recuperar apenas a parte relevante com uma expressão regular, e depois usar um [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

Um exemplo de expressão regular seria uma como esta:

```
\d+\-\d+\-\d+T\d+\:\d+\:\d+
```

Um exemplo completo se pareceria com isto:

```
final String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
final String dateOnOWL = "[\"2015-06-30T16:38:53\"^^xsd:dateTime]";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\-\\d+\\-\\d+T\\d+\\:\\d+\\:\\d+");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dateOnOWL);

if (matcher.find()) {
    final String result = matcher.group();
    final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    final Date date = sdf.parse(result);
    System.out.println(date);
} else {
    System.out.println(String.format("Padrão não encontrado em %s", dateOnOWL));
}
```

A expressão regular é só um exemplo de como aplicar, você pode melhorá-la se for utilizar esta abordagem.

A forma simples é informando a partir de qual posição o formatador (o `DateFormat`) deve começar a utilizar o padrão que estamos utilizando. Para fazer isto você deve utilizar um [`ParsePosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParsePosition.html) informando que iremos iniciar da posição de índice **2**, ou seja, de **2** de **2015**. Como o padrão irá apenas até os segundos, o formatador irá desconsiderar o restante.

Um exemplo seria algo assim, que gera o mesmo resultado:

```
final String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
final String dateOnOWL = "[\"2015-06-30T16:38:53\"^^xsd:dateTime]";
final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
final ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(2);
final Date date = sdf.parse(dateOnOWL, position);
System.out.println(date);
```